# Does event stories make sense?

Tags: storybook

My team is working on in-house component library and we are using Storybook to document and test our components. I would like to know if it make sense to create a stories for component events or if there is better way to ensure events work as expected? Additionally from the documentation perspective, my thoughts would be it would be good to code sample for each event. However, the storybooks from other companies I seen have no stories for events.